# Twillo,I am building an IVR system and need to this-

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am building an IVR system so I need to Check if my Twilio number is busy with any other call then I want to forward the call to another twillo number.So can I implement that.
Or how should I check if my twillo number is busy with any call.Or any way I can check if my twillo number is currently on call.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to do this? Twilio supports concurrent inbound calls.

> For inbound calls, Twilio places no limitation on the rate at which an account can receive inbound calls.The correct type of phone number should be used depending on the expected maximum number of concurrent inbound calls. Landline and Mobile phone numbers are tested to receive 20 concurrent calls. For higher inbound call volumes, Toll-Free numbers should be used. Twilio will make an HTTP request to the request URL for each call received at your Twilio number. Therefore, please make sure your server is capable of handling the load if you are expecting a large amount of concurrent inbound traffic.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183648-Sending-and-Receiving-Limitations-on-Calls-and-SMS-Messages

Comment: I want to dial an other agent number if the first agent is on call with someone already.

Comment: What do you want to do if the number of concurrent incoming calls is greater than the number of your agents? Maybe <ENQUEUE>  [ https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue ] and <QUEUE> [ https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/queue ] is what you want.

Comment: I have three twilio number like A,B,C  and a user calls on number A, when user call on  number C we have arrange a system to ask his choice to press on to talk to sales and sales numbers are B,C so user press 1 then we try to connect with B but what happence is B is already on call with another user so we make him to talk this new too so what I want to check if B is busy then transfer it to C

Comment: hey can look my this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42417185/when-we-make-call-using-rest-api-then-what-twiml-we-use-on-that-url-parameter].I have kinda arrange this one from my end.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'd suggest checking out [TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/taskrouter) as its built specifically for scenarios like this. Agents can set their own availability status and then you create workflows to take inbound calls and match them to an available agent who matches whatever criteria you define.

If there are not agents available who match the customer gets queued until one becomes available or until you decide to move them to a different experience (like a call-back instead of a hold queue).

There is a [PHP quickstart for TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/taskrouter) that I'd suggest starting with.